# Alfresco Maven - Simple Module Jar

Tags: maven, alfresco

I am trying to create an alfresco extension jar module as described on
http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/dev-extensions-packaging-techniques-jar-files.html and use the sample Simple Module available on https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-sdk-samples/tree/master/samples/alfresco-simple-module/repo
but when I change the SDK from 2.1.0 to 2.2.0, the project does not build complaining about

Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Failed to get resource: alfresco/ibatis/#resource.dialect#/activities-insert-SqlMap.xml

Any advice much appreciated.

Regards,
Kavi

Comment: @imagine I did check the link you pointed out before raising this case. The mentioned link refers to using the ALL IN ONE project but I am using the Alfresco Extension jar module project and I also tried adding the suggested dependency in my pom but it did not work.

Comment: Does it work when you leave the SDK version unchanged? Usually an SDK version change requires much more than simply changing the version.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following `pom.xml` changes:

- Change Alfresco SDK version:

  ```
  <parent>
      <groupId>org.alfresco.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>alfresco-sdk-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
  </parent>
  ```
- Customize Alfresco version:

  ```
  <properties>
      <!-- The SDK 2.2.x is supported only for Alfresco 5.1.x Community 
           and above or Alfresco Enterprise 5.1 and above -->
      <alfresco.version>5.1.e</alfresco.version> <!-- or 5.2.b-EA -->
      <!-- ... -->
  </properties>
  ```
- Add H2 Database scripts dependency:

  ```
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>${alfresco.groupId}</groupId>
          <artifactId>alfresco-repository</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Bring in the H2 Database scripts -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>${alfresco.groupId}</groupId>
          <artifactId>alfresco-repository</artifactId>
          <version>${alfresco.version}</version>
          <classifier>h2scripts</classifier>
          <scope>test</scope>
          <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                  <groupId>*</groupId>
                  <artifactId>*</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
      </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  ```
- Fix version of `alfresco-rad`:

  ```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.alfresco.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>alfresco-rad</artifactId>
          <version>${maven.alfresco.version}</version>
      </dependency>
  ```

... or just clone [my fork with these changes](https://github.com/wildloop/alfresco-sdk-samples) :)

Now, delete folders `alf_data_dev` and `target` and run:

```
 mvn clean package
```